# Improve performance of dataframe-like structure

Tags: python, performance, numpy, data-structures

I'm facing a data-structure challenge regarding a process in my code code in which I need to count the frequency of strings in positive and negative examples.
It's a large bottleneck and I don't seem to be able to find a better solution.

I have to go through every long strings in the dataset, and extract substrings, of which I need to count the frequency. In a perfect world, a pandas dataframe of the following shape would be perfect:

At the end, the expected structure is something like

```
string | frequency positive | frequency negative
________________________________________________
str1   |        5           |         7 
str2   |        2           |         4 
...
```

However, for obvious performance limits, this is not acceptable.
My solution is to use a dictionary to track the rows, and a `Nx2` numpy matrix to track the frequency. This is also done because after this, I need to have the frequency in a `Nx2` numpy matrix anyway.

Currently, my solution is something like this:

```py
        str_freq = np.zeros((N, 2), dtype=np.uint32)
        str_dict = {}
        str_dict_counter = 0

        for i, string in enumerate(dataset):
            substrings = extract(string) # substrings is a List[str]

            for substring in substrings:
                row = str_dict.get(substring, None)

                if row is None:
                    str_dict[substring] = str_dict_counter
                    row = str_dict_counter
                    str_dict_counter += 1

                str_freq[row, target[i]] += 1 # target[i] is equal to 1 or 0
```

However, it is really the bottleneck of my code, and I'd like to speed it up.

Some things about this code are imcompressible, for instance the `extract(string)`, so that loop has to remain. However, if possible there is no problem with using parallel processing.

What I'm wondering especially is if there is a way to improve the inner loop. Python is known to be bad with loops, and this one seems a bit pointless, however since we can't (to my knowledge) do multiple get and sets to dictionaries like we can with numpy arrays, I don't know how I could improve it.

What do you suggest doing? Is the only solution to re-write in some lower level language?

I also though about using SQL-lite, however I don't know if it's worth it.
For the record, this has to take in about 10MB of data, it currently takes about 45 seconds, but needs to be done repeatedly with new data each time.

**EDIT:** Added example to test yourself

```
import random
import string
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_random_alphaNumeric_string(stringLength=8):
    return bytes(bytearray(np.random.randint(0,256,stringLength,dtype=np.uint8)))


def generate_dataset(n=10000):
    d = []
    for i in range(n):
        rnd_text = get_random_alphaNumeric_string(stringLength=1000)
        d.append(rnd_text)

    return d


def test_dict(dataset):
    pattern = re.compile(b"(q.{3})")
    target = np.random.randint(0,2,len(dataset))

    str_freq = np.zeros((len(dataset)*len(dataset[0]), 2), dtype=np.uint32)
    str_dict = {}
    str_dict_counter = 0



    for i, string in enumerate(dataset):
        substrings = pattern.findall(string) # substrings is a List[str]

        for substring in substrings:
            row = str_dict.get(substring, None)

            if row is None:
                str_dict[substring] = str_dict_counter
                row = str_dict_counter
                str_dict_counter += 1

            str_freq[row, target[i]] += 1 # target[i] is equal to 1 or 0

    return str_dict, str_freq[:str_dict_counter,:]

def test_df(dataset):
    pattern = re.compile(b"(q.{3})")
    target = np.random.randint(0,2,len(dataset))

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["str","pos","neg"])
    df.astype(dtype={"str":bytes, "pos":int, "neg":int}, copy=False)
    df = df.set_index("str")

    for i, string in enumerate(dataset):
        substrings = pattern.findall(string) # substrings is a List[str]

        for substring in substrings:
            check = substring in df.index

            if not check:
                row = [0,0]
                row[target[i]] = 1
                df.loc[substring] = row 
            else:
                df.loc[substring][target[i]] += 1

    return df


dataset = generate_dataset(1000000)

d,f = test_dict(dataset) # takes ~10 seconds on my laptop

# to get the value of some key, say b'q123'
f[d[b'q123'],:]

d = test_df(dataset) # takes several minutes (hasn't finished yet)
# the same but with a dataframe
d.loc[b'q123']
```

Comment: What's obvious about performance limits on `pandas`? Do you mean you can't use `pandas` at all (then why are you using `numpy`?), or perhaps you just haven't came across the right methods? I'm not sure if it's healthy to assume some parts of your code just can't be changed, or perhaps I just fundamentally misunderstood the question.  Currently it's just too abstract for me, if you have some concrete [mre] with I/O that might help.

Comment: Hi @r.ook, finally got to adding a minimal reproducible example. As for the pandas performance, I had used it in the past and read about how slow it is at appending values (which is what needs to be done here). However, your comment made me want to try it again. As expected, it takes a lot longer than a dictionary. If you find a way to make it faster, I have nothing against pandas per-se, however it just doesn't seem adapted to this use case unfortunately

Comment: I feel there's a lot of extraneous code in that sample... For instance iterating through the `dataset` instead of using the `df` you already set up feels like it's missing the point.  The `list.append` will also eat up a lot of your time during `generate_dataset`.  If you could better illustrate what you want from the `df` it might be easier to understand.  For instance, how do you determine the `str, pos, neg` columns? A more concrete sample of a snippet I/O might help visualize this better.  Right now I'm *guessing* you want just the `q.{3}` matches but not sure what else.